# Traefik - Docker Swarm - basic routing issue

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

My config is a simple Docker Swarm (on Docker for Windows) with a Treafik container and a very simple Spring Boot 'echo' container.

I would like to forward a browser request for 'localhost/traefik' to the Traefik dashboard and 'localhost/echo/something' to a simple Sprint Boot echo application.

Expected to work:

> ```
> localhost/treafik => gives a "Gateway timeout"
> localhost/echo/something => gives a "Gateway timeout"
> ```

Expected not to work, but bypass Traefik (incorrectly):

> ```
> localhost:8080 => shows the Traefik dashboard
> localhost:8082/echo/something => { "status":"something" }
> ```

How can I improve the docker-compose.yml file to get the expected result? Can this have to do with 'networking'? When creating any network, even an overlay, gave error messages.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --api --docker
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - //k/data/slackbot/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost;PathPrefixStrip:/traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
  slackbotsimple:
    image: solvedshared/slackbotsimple:latest
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost;PathPrefix:/echo"
      - "traefik.port=8082"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.backend=slackbotsimple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue was a networking issue. Solved, thanks to clever Jim.

The other issue was that I used the wrong port number. To route from the frontend '/echo' to the backend, the 'ports' section is NOT used. I could route directly to the exposed port of the slackbot application!

Take a look at the ports config: only 80 is available.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --api --docker
    restart: always
    networks:
      - slackbotnet
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - //k/data/slackbot/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=slackbotnet"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost;PathPrefixStrip:/traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
  slackbotsimple:
    image: solvedshared/slackbotsimple:latest
    networks:
      - slackbotnet
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=slackbotnet"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost;PathPrefix:/echo"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.backend=slackbotsimple"

networks:
  slackbotnet:
    name: slackbotnet
```